# Phone call click for textview

Tags: java, android, textview

Okay so I've looked and tried to make sense of some other code that I've found but nothing has been working out for me. I'm trying to get the user to click the textview and have it take them to their phones dial-er.

Here's the Java:

```
public class Info extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.moreinfo);
    Button appoint =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAppoint);
    TextView phone =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneTxt);
    String url = phone.getText().toString();
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
    appoint.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(Info.this, EmailContact.class));
        }
    });

    phone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+phone.getText().toString().trim()));
            startActivity(callIntent );
        }
});
}
}
```

I've also put android: clickable = true so I don't see if that's the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there any error that occurs?

Comment: It's showing a red underline under "phone" in ("tel:+"+phone.getText() There aren't any errors but what is it that I need to do in order for that line to go away? I tried putting the actual phone number and nothing as well as phoneTxt with the same result.

Comment: Sounds like a compilation error then, try reading the rrror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description its red because if you're going to use an class method level object within an anonymous obejct, the object must be defined as final.

```
final TextView phone =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneTxt);
```

And for further measure, ensure you are using the right permission to do the call action in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Your method worked! I initially put TextView as final but I didn't think that was correct. I didn't know about the permission either so that's always a plus! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Change `phone.getText().toString().trim()` to use the View object supplied to the onclick method:

```
phone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+((TextView)arg0).getText().toString().trim()));
    startActivity(callIntent );
}
});
```

Additionally, if you just want to show the dialer with a phone number loaded, you're using the wrong intent action, `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL` will show the dialer.  The `Intent.ACTION_CALL` that you're using will actually initiate the phone call, and to make that work, you need to add the appropriate permission to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```